# OneDrive notifications through Microsoft GRAPH

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm building an app that should get notifications when people interact with their one-drives.
So I subscribed to a specific Office365 user (who owns a oneDrive) and I successfully receive uploaded/deleted/modified notifications for each of the files in the drive.

Now I'm interested in getting notifications for **share** and **download** operations as well.

I noticed that if the user share a file I do get a notification that contains `shared` section (dictionary) and inside it, there's a `scope` key with value `'users'`. That's nice but I would like to know with who the file was shared, is it also possible? also it seems that notification is only send for the first share - any info about why is that?

I also would like to receive notifications when someone shares a file with me, is it possible? from a naive check I made (sharing a file from a different office365 user) I didn't get any notification...

And what about downloading? That also doesn't seem to be triggering any notification, is that supported somehow?

I read some of Micorosft GRAPH documentation but couldn't find any relevant info on share and download drive files notifications.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point the OneDrive API does not support notifications for sharing or download. We'll make note of your feedback, though. Also please raise this request in our [uservoice](https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/913708/) so others can vote on it, too.